# extract date and time from a text string with multiple dates and text characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

2 questions one

how will i get the earlier date from this one cell for example i have all this notes in one

**2020-04-07 17:35:43 - Mark 
Quality Check complete: Created as requested

SNOW ID =Csdsd
Note: Application Data registered
2020-04-03 12:13:45 - Mark
~ Notes: Quality check**

question i want to get 2020-04-03 12:13:45 only that is in the lowest part of the cell how will i do that?

also
second question what if i only have this in a cell

**2020-04-03 12:13:45 - Mark
~ Notes: Quality check**

i want to get the date and time 2020-04-03 12:13:45 only

kindly help

Comment: If *Mark* is someone's name and it changes often (e.g. *Bob, Susan,* etc) then you need a user defined function that utilizes RegEx.

Comment: start with the formula `SEARCH()` and the text you want to find is a pattern match like `"????-??-??"`. You'll need to combine this with other formulas to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date/time is always in the format shown (and there is nothing else in the string that has the same format), if you have **O365** with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use this formula:

```
=MIN(--MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("????-??-?? ??:??:??",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(255),19))*SEQUENCE(255),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-??-?? ??:??:??",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(255),19)))),1))),19))
```

If you do not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
=MIN(--MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("????-??-?? ??:??:??",MID(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1)),19))*ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1)),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-??-?? ??:??:??",MID(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1)),19)))),1))),19))
```

The formulas should work no matter how many dates are in the string

[image]

***Note:***  If your strings might be longer than 255 characters, change the factor in the `ROW(INDEX(…` or `SEQUENCE(…` function accordingly.  (Or replace it with `LEN(A1)`)

***Note2:*** It is possible that earlier versions of Excel may require this be entered as an **array** formula, by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Both formula are working +1 ☺

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your **second** question.  This little UDF will scan a string and retrieve the **first instance** of a date/time in the format you require:

```
Public Function GrabDate(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, subS As String
    Dim pattrn As String

    pattrn = "####[-]##[-]##[ ]##[:]##[:]##"
    L = Len(s)

    For i = 1 To L
        subS = Mid(s, i, 19)
        If subS Like pattrn Then
            GrabDate = subS
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    GrabDate = ""
End Function
```

[image]

You may be able to modify it to solve your first question.

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student,, you have used `only one Date & Time` the `second one` ,, but OP text has 2 Date Time value and OP wants to get the lowest one !!

Comment: @RajeshS  **You are correct.** The OP asked **2** questions, I only answered the second.